# Adding custom environment to CreateEnvironmentBlock()

Tags: windows, process

I'm using CreateProcessAsUser + CreateEnvironmentBlock to copy environment variables from another process.

Is it possible to add custom environment variable to the result of `CreateEnvironmentBlock` call?

Answer (score 1):

The environment block is just a series of null terminated strings (ending with a double-null terminated string).  Just parse it, insert your new key/value pairs, and save back to a buffer.  I wrote some code to get you started:

```
wstring lowercase(const wstring& s)
{
    std::wstring str(s);
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
        [](wchar_t c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    return str;
}

wstring appendToEnvironmentBlock(const void* pEnvBlock, const wstring& varname, const wstring& varvalue)
{
    map<wstring, wstring> env;
    const wchar_t* currentEnv = (const wchar_t*)pEnvBlock;
    wstring result;

    // parse the current block into a map of key/value pairs
    while (*currentEnv)
    {
        wstring keyvalue = currentEnv;
        wstring key;
        wstring value;

        size_t pos = keyvalue.find_last_of(L'=');
        if (pos != wstring::npos)
        {
            key = keyvalue.substr(0, pos);
            value = keyvalue; // entire string
        }
        else
        {
            // ??? no '=' sign, just save it off
            key = keyvalue;
            value = keyvalue;
        }
        value += L'\0'; // reappend the null char

        env[lowercase(key)] = value;
        currentEnv += keyvalue.size() + 1;
    }

    // add the new key and value to the map
    if (varvalue.empty())
    {
        env.erase(lowercase(varname)); // if varvalue is empty, just assume this means, "delete this environment variable"
    }
    else
    {
        env[lowercase(varname)] = varname + L'=' + varvalue + L'\0';
    }

    // serialize the map into the buffer we just allocated
    for (auto& item : env)
    {
        result += item.second;
    }
    result += L'\0';
    auto ptr = result.c_str();

    return result;
}
```

Then let's say you want to insert "NewEnvironmentVariable=GoSeahawks!!!" into the environment block.  Invoke as follows:

```
::CreateEnvironmentBlock(&envblock, hToken, TRUE);
wstring updatedBlock = appendToEnvironmentBlock(envblock, L"NewEnvironmentVariable", L"GoSeahawks!!!");
CreateProcessAsUser(token, ..., updatedBlock.c_str(), ...);
```

Comment: Having to implement this is tedious, but unfortunately necessary. The system does already implement this functionality for arbitrary environment blocks in the undocumented NT API function `RtlSetEnvironmentVariable`, which gets called internally by `CreateEnvironmentBlock`. But they've never bothered to support it in the Windows API.